# TypeError: Error in invocation of debugger.detach; No matching signature

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on the chrome.debugger Chrome extensions API, here's the simple example:

```js
chrome.debugger.attach(target, "1.2")
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(target, "Input.insertText", { text: "test."  })
chrome.debugger.detach(target, "1.2")
```

And in the last line, I get the error:

```
VM7521:1 Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of debugger.detach(debugger.Debuggee target, optional function callback): No matching signature.
    at <anonymous>:1:17
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I've solved the problem:

```
chrome.debugger.detach(target)
```

Instead of

```
chrome.debugger.detach(target, "1.2")
```

I noticed this while reading the Chrome extension samples on Github:

[chrome-extensions-samples/background.js at e716678b67fd30a5876a552b9665e9f847d6d84b · GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/e716678b67fd30a5876a552b9665e9f847d6d84b/mv2-archive/api/debugger/pause-resume/background.js)

It didn't have the "version" argument in the `detach` so.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Close visual studio and open, it should solve your problem

Comment: At the first place I'm not using visual studio.

Comment: It's just on a normal Chrome browser with a normal Chrome devtools.